# Get clicked object from ItemsControl and populate Popup with its properties

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got an `ItemsControl` which displays objects from a list from my viewmodel. I also have code to display a `Popup` when the user click on an item in the ItemsControl. However I don't know how to get the actual object from the clicked item to read its properties and display them in the `Popup`.

I've got a `Click` event handler for the `Button` (which is used to display my items in the `ItemsControl`) and I tried to see in the debugger if the button contains the desired object but apparently it doesn't.

How else can I get the object and populate the popup with its properties?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RecipientsNames}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="btnConvoContact" Click="BtnConvoContact_Click"
                    Background="White" Foreground="Black" Cursor="Hand"
                    Width="Auto" Height="14" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0 0 6 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="12" Margin="0 -2 0 -2"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Is your popup defined in XAML?

Comment: clicked Button should have actual data object in `DataContext` property. I would suggest to use ListBox instead of ItemsControl (since ListBox suports selection) and bind Poput to SelectedItem property

Comment: Yes, the Popup is in XAML.

But is it possible to set up ListBox the same way I've set up the ItemsControl (all items are contained in a StackPanel)? Is it enough to just replace the ItemsControl with a ListBox or do I need to make more changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast the `DataContext` of the `sender` argument in the event handler to your data type:

```
private void BtnConvoContact_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    var dataObject = btn.DataContext as YourDataClass;
}
```

Comment: OK, seems to work! And then I need to assign the dataObject to the Popup's DataContext (`myPopup.DataContext=dataObject`) and can reference the dataObject's properties in popup's XAML: `<Popup><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}"/></Popup>`